# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I tried to build my spring-boot project with jpa and without jdbc.
But the following error occurs :

-> Now I edited my codes and configurations using spring datasource, but I also got exception T T

-> I have configured mysql datasource but the Error occurs.

My Application codes are like followings :

```
    :::


    @SpringBootApplication
    public class OAuth2Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer   {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new SpringApplicationBuilder(OAuth2Application.class)
            .initializers(new OAuth2ApplicationContextInitializer())
            .run(args);
       }
   :::
   }


   [application.yml]

    :::
    #spring.h2.console:
    #  enabled: true
    #  path: /h2-console
    #
    # 외부 DB 설정시 아래의 주석을 활성화 시킨 후 관련 DB 설정 정보를 입력한다.
    #spring:
    #  datasource:
    #    url:               jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/api;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    #    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    #    username: sa
    #    password:
    # DataSource
    spring.datasource:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db'
      username: user
      password: pass

    #
    # MongoDB data
    spring.data:
      mongodb: 
        #uri: mongodb://localhost/
        host: localhost
        port: 27017 
        database: db
        username: user
        password: pass
        repositories.enabled: true
    #
    mybatis:
      config-location: 'classpath:mybatis-config.xml'

    [my exception log]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    :::
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]
   :::
   DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath
```

Comment: I'd say remove all annotaitons except @SpringBootAppliation and make your JDBC work, then add the OAuth stuff. Can you also please post your application.properties / application.yml ?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` ?  That is the one which autoconfigures a `DataSource`

Comment: I want to use jpa for mongoldb only...

Comment: After deleting another annotation, I got also exception as follwoings : Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).  and Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception

Answer (score 0):

mvn install -> install & Test run got the error !!!
But mvn spring-boot:run do work good !!!

I have no idea of Test run problem...